# GoJS: How can I change Node fill color?

Tags: javascript, nodes, diagram, fill, gojs

I'm using GoJS to make the diagram.

My diagram configuration (the example from the official documentation):

```
function init() {
    //......
    // define the Node template
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Auto",
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the TextBlock
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
                {
                    parameter1: 20,  // the corner has a large radius
                    fill: $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 201, 0)", 1: "rgb(254, 162, 0)" }),
                    stroke: null,
                    portId: "",  // this Shape is the Node's port, not the whole Node
                    fromLinkable: true, fromLinkableSelfNode: true, fromLinkableDuplicates: true,
                    toLinkable: true, toLinkableSelfNode: true, toLinkableDuplicates: true,
                    cursor: "pointer"
                }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
                {
                    font: "bold 11pt helvetica, bold arial, sans-serif",
                    editable: true  // editing the text automatically updates the model data
                },
                new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );
//......
}
```

I'm creating the nodes in the following way:

```
var nodeOperations = new Object();

    for (var i = 0; i < countState; i++) {           
            var json = {'id': i, 'loc': nodesCenters[i].x +' '+nodesCenters[i].y, 'text': markedStateTable['digitStates'][i] + ', ' + markedStateTable['namedStates'][i]};

            nodes.push(json);
    }
```

And now I need programmatically change the fill color for specific node. I'm trying this code:

```
var data = myDiagram.model.findNodeDataForKey(0);

    myDiagram.model.setDataProperty(data, "fill", "green");
```

But after that, my chart doesn't display. And there are no error in console. Should I set the new shape for the node? Or how can I do that? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please specify the fill color in the nodeArray

```
var nodeDataArray = [
    { key: 1, text: "Name", fill: "#ff5722", stroke: "#4d90fe", description: "geethu" }];
```

Then add binding to the textBlock as

> ```
>  $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", {
>                     fill: "#cce6ff" // the default fill, if there is no data-binding
>         }, new go.Binding("fill", "fill"))
> ```

```
 myDiagram.nodeTemplate =

    $(go.Node, "Horizontal", {
            isTreeExpanded: false,
            click: showDetail
        },
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", {
                fill: "#cce6ff", // the default fill, if there is no data-binding
                stroke: "#6699ff",
                height: 40,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                portId: "",
                cursor: "pointer", // the Shape is the port, not the whole Node
            }, new go.Binding("fill", "fill")),
            $(go.TextBlock, {
                    editable: true
                },
                new go.Binding("text", "text"))
        ),
        $("TreeExpanderButton", { alignment: go.Spot.Bottom, alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Top }, { visible: true })
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use switch statement based on the node you want to fill based on the property value. Assuming you have a property named 'namedStates' based on which you node color should change, here is my example:

```
 $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
    name: "SHAPE",
    fill: "red",
    stroke: null,
    fromLinkable: true,
    toLinkable: true,
    cursor: "pointer"
}, new go.Binding("fill", "namedStates", function(type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            return "#FF4081";
        case 2:
            return "#303F9F";
        case 3:
            return "#00796B";
        case 4:
            return "#FF5722";
        case 5:
            return "#5D4037";
        case 6:
            return "#7B1FA2";
        default:
            return '#8BC34A';

    }
})),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a data binding for fill or the value in the node data is meaningless. After all, what would it mean to have `data.fill` if you had multiple shapes with multiple different fills?

So add `new go.Binding("fill")` to the relevant shape you want to change:

```
function init() {
    //......
    // define the Node template
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Auto",
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the TextBlock
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
                {
                    parameter1: 20,  // the corner has a large radius
                    fill: $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 201, 0)", 1: "rgb(254, 162, 0)" }),
                    stroke: null,
                    portId: "",  // this Shape is the Node's port, not the whole Node
                    fromLinkable: true, fromLinkableSelfNode: true, fromLinkableDuplicates: true,
                    toLinkable: true, toLinkableSelfNode: true, toLinkableDuplicates: true,
                    cursor: "pointer"
                },
            new go.Binding("fill") // NEW
            ),
            $(go.TextBlock,
                {
                    font: "bold 11pt helvetica, bold arial, sans-serif",
                    editable: true  // editing the text automatically updates the model data
                },
                new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );
//......
}
```

> But after that, my chart doesn't display.

I don't know why that would be happening. Use go-debug.js to see more warnings.

See also this tutorial on GraphObject manipulation, including using setDataProperty: http://gojs.net/latest/learn/graphobject.html

Comment: Seems to me there should be a selector for the element that has the value you want to use...... new go.Binding("fill",[element])

Comment: Huh? You can already set a second argument corresponding to a data property, eg: `new go.Binding("fill", "color")`